# How to zoom properly in OpenGL ES 2

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I've a 3d-model in OpenGL ES in Android. I've already implemented swipe-gestures for translating, rotating and zooming into the model. Everything but the zooming works fine. I'm not sure what I'm missing or what I have to change but I'm not able to zoom into my model.

The model is a building. What I'd like to do is to zoom into the different floors of the building. But no matter how I change my implementation, I'm not able to do this.

Either the building disappears when I zoom in or the zoom has a limitation so that I can't zoom into it further....

First of all I decreased the field of view by modifying the Matrix:

`frustumM(matrix, 0, -ratio/zoom, ratio/zoom, -1/zoom, 1/zoom, nearPlane, farPlane)`.

Someone told me, that this is not the correct approach and I should modify the eyeZ value like:

`eyeZ = -1.0/zoom`

The first approach is working, but I'd like to know what my mistake with the second approach is, because it has the issues I mentioned in the beginning.

My renderer-class is the following:

```
 public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

private float[] mModelMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mMVMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];

private float nearPlaneDistance = 1f;
private float farPlaneDistance = 200f;

private float modelRatio = 1.0f;

private int offset = 0;
private float eyeX = 0;
private float eyeY = 0;
private float eyeZ = -1;
private float centerX = 0f;
private float centerY = 0f;
private float centerZ = 0f;
private float upX = 0f;
private float upY = 1.0f;
private float upZ = 0.0f;

private float mZoomLevel = 1f;

private float defaultRotationX = 100.0f; //building otherwise on the wrong side
private float defaultRotationZ = 180.0f; //building otherwise on the wrong side
private float rotationX = defaultRotationX;
private float rotationY = 0.0f;
private float rotationZ = defaultRotationZ;

private float translateX = 0.0f;
private float translateY = 0.0f;
private float translateZ = 0.0f;

private float scaleFactor = 20.0f; //no matter what scale factor -> it's not possible to zoom into the building...

private float ratio;
private float width;
private float height;

private List<IDrawableObject> drawableObjects;
public Model3D model3d;

public MyGLRenderer(Model3D model3d) {
    this.model3d = model3d;
    getModelScale();
}

private void getModelScale() {
    float highestValue = (model3d.width > model3d.height) ? model3d.width
            : model3d.height;
    modelRatio = 2f / highestValue;
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
    // Set the background frame color
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    drawableObjects = ... ; //to much detail, basically getting triangles
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
    float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];

    // Draw background color
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // model is in origin-solution too big
    Matrix.scaleM(mModelMatrix, 0, modelRatio * scaleFactor, modelRatio
            * scaleFactor, modelRatio * scaleFactor);

    Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, translateX, translateY, translateZ);

    rotateModel(mModelMatrix, rotationX, rotationY, rotationZ, true);

    // Set the camera position (View matrix)
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, offset, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ / mZoomLevel,
            centerX, centerY, centerZ, upX, upY, upZ);

    // combine the model with the view matrix
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);

    // this projection matrix is applied to object coordinates
    // in the onDrawFrame() method
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, 1, -1,
            nearPlaneDistance, farPlaneDistance);

    // Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVMatrix, 0);

    for (IDrawableObject d : drawableObjects) {
        d.draw(mMVPMatrix);
    }
}

private void rotateModel(float[] mModelMatrix, Float x, Float y, Float z,
        boolean rotateAroundCenter) {
    // translation for rotating the model around its center
    if (rotateAroundCenter) {
        Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, (model3d.width / 2f), 0,
                (model3d.height / 2f));
    }
    if (x != null) {
        Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, x, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }
    if (y != null) {
        Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, y, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    }
    if (z != null) {
        Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, z, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    // translation back to the origin
    if (rotateAroundCenter) {
        Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, -(model3d.width / 2f), 0,
                -(model3d.height / 2f));
    }
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
    // Adjust the viewport based on geometry changes,
    // such as screen rotation
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    ratio = (float) width / height;
}

public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode) {
    // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

    // add the source code to the shader and compile it
    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

    return shader;
}

public int getFPS() {
    return lastMFPS;
}

public static void checkGlError(String glOperation) {
    int error;
    while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
        Log.e(TAG, glOperation + ": glError " + error);
        throw new RuntimeException(glOperation + ": glError " + error);
    }
}

public void setZoom(float zoom) {
    this.mZoomLevel = zoom;
}

public void setDistance(float distance) {
    eyeZ = distance;
}

public float getDistance() {
    return eyeZ;
}

public float getRotationX() {
    return rotationX;
}

public void setRotationX(float rotationX) {
    this.rotationX = defaultRotationX + rotationX;
}

public float getRotationY() {
    return rotationY;
}

public void setRotationY(float rotationY) {
    this.rotationY = rotationY;
}

public float getRotationZ() {
    return rotationZ;
}

public void setRotationZ(float rotationZ) {
    this.rotationZ = defaultRotationZ + rotationZ;
}

public float getFarPlane() {
    return farPlaneDistance;
}

public float getNearPlane() {
    return nearPlaneDistance;
}

public void addTranslation(float mPosX, float mPosY) {
    this.translateX = mPosX;
    this.translateY = mPosY;
}

public void downPressed() {
    translateX -= 10;
}

public void upPressed() {
    translateX += 10;
}

public void actionMoved(float mPosX, float mPosY) {
    float translationX = (mPosX / width);
    float translationY = -(mPosY / height);
    addTranslation(translationX, translationY);
}

public float getmZoomLevel() {
    return mZoomLevel;
}

public void setmZoomLevel(float mZoomLevel) {
    this.mZoomLevel = mZoomLevel;
}

public float getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public float getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setTranslation(Float x, Float y, Float z) {
    if (x != null) {
        this.translateX = -x;
    }
    if (y != null) {
        this.translateY = y;
    }
    if (z != null) {
        this.translateZ = -z;
    }
}

public void setRotation(Float x, Float y, Float z) {
    if (x != null) {
        this.rotationX = defaultRotationX + x;
    }
    if (y != null) {
        this.rotationY = y;
    }
    if (z != null) {
        this.rotationZ = defaultRotationZ + z;
    }
}

public void setScale(float scale) {
    this.mZoomLevel = scale;
}

public float getDefaultRotationX() {
    return defaultRotationX;
}
```

}

Do you see any mistake I'm currently doing? You can also have a look into the github repository: https://github.com/Dalanie/OpenGL-ES/tree/master/buildingGL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must define what you mean by "zoom". In the scenario of a perspective projection, there are a few possibilities:

1. You change the field of view. This is analogous to the zoom of cameras, where zooming results in changing the focal width.
2. You just scale the model before the projection.
3. You change the distance of the model (nearer to the camera to zoom in, farer away to zoom out)

The variant 1 is what you did by changing the frustum. In my opinion, that is the most intuitive effect. At least to someone who is used to cameras. ALso note that this has the same effect as upscaling some sub-rectangle of the 2d projected image to fill the whole screen.

Changing `eyeZ` is approach 3. But now you must be carefol to not move the object out of the viewing volume (which seems to be the issue you are describing). Ideally you would modify the frustum here, too. But to keep the field of view, while moving the near/far planes so that the object always stays inbetween. Note that this requires changing all 6 values of the frustum, what stays the same should be the ratios `left/near`, `right/near`, `top/near` and `bottom/near` to keep the FOV/aspect you had before.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solutions! Quick question before I mark the answer as correct: What would you suggest? In case you have a building and you want to zoom into the different rooms/floors.  Like you said 3 makes some problems and it seems more complex to change 6 different values. 2 has the same problem. Should I stick to (1) ?

Comment: @Frame91: well, that is hard to tell. I really can't imagine how zooming alone would be the way to go for a building with several rooms. I mean to inspect a room, they eye point should certainly be insde the room. So zooming is not the operation that comes to my mind. I think I would use some fly-through metaphor (which basically ends up as variant of approach 3, but without changing the frustum at all). But I really don't know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hey, I don't need to "inspect" the room, I just want to "fly" over the room with the camera so I would do some kind of zoom and a little rotation/translation to get this done I guess... Nothing fancy at all

Comment: But however, eyeZ is not working and the two other approaches from you  make some trouble as well :( Second and Third approach from you have the problem I mentioned in the beginning. After some zoom in, they disappear because of the nearplane... :(

Comment: @Frame91: well, as I said: adapt the near and far planes to cover the range you need.

Comment: and if the near plane is already at 0.01 and I still want to zoom more? Do i need to scale the model up? thanks for all the answers so far!

Comment: @Frame91: you should really analyze where your objects are placed relative to the viewing frustum. Nobody can tell what a near plane of 0.01 does mean in _your_ scene.

Comment: thanks... i'll have a further look ;) But near plane of 0.01 is almost the minimum isn't it? So no matter what my scene looks like, I still have to scale the object up or am I wrong?

Comment: @Frame91: well. that depends. when your objects is in the range 0.0000001 to 0.00001, 0.01 is far from the minimum.